# How do I convert a JavaScript forEach loop/function to CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, coffeescript, d3.js, crossfilter

**Background**: I'm trying to convert some JavaScript code which uses the the [Crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter) library with [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) data visualization library into [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

What is the best way to convert a JavaScript forEach loop/function into CoffeeScript?

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
// A little coercion, since the CSV is untyped.
flights.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.index = i;
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.delay = +d.delay;
    d.distance = +d.distance;
});
```

Can CoffeeScript do an in-line function inside a loop?  Right now I'm guess I need it broken out into a function and loop:

```
coerce = (d) ->
     d.index    = 1
     d.date     = parseDate(d.date)
     d.delay    = +d.delay
     d.distance = +d.distance

coerce(flights) for d in flights
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

use a *comprehension*

```
for d, i in flights
  console.log d, i
```

The code above translates to

```
var d, i, _i, _len;

for (i = _i = 0, _len = flights.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
  d = flights[i];
  console.log(d, i);
}
```

so you can see `d` and `i` are what you want them to be.

[Go here](http://coffeescript.org/) and search for "forEach" for some examples.

Finally, look at the first comment for some more useful info.

Comment: Just so OP knows, this is not equivalent to the JS code. It'll iterate over undeclared properties, whereas a `forEach` won't. Also, it doesn't create a new closure during each iteration, so if there are handlers created, they may not behave as expected.

Answer (score 14):

The direct translation is:

```
flights.forEach (d, i) ->
  d.index = i
  d.date = parseDate(d.date)
  d.delay = +d.delay
  d.distance = +d.distance
```

or you can use an idiomatic version:

```
for d,i in flights
  d.index = i
  d.date = parseDate(d.date)
  d.delay = +d.delay
  d.distance = +d.distance
```

Comment: That seems to result in a `for` loop. A `forEach` has subtle *(or perhaps not so subtle)* differences.

Comment: I was speaking WRT the second version. +1 for the first, which is the proper equivalent. I don't remember if it was there when I commented.

Answer (score 5):

forEach has the advantage of wrapping each iteration in a closure. so asynchronous calls can preserve the correct values. 
the coffeescript way of doing this (without actually using forEach) is

```
for d,i in flights
  do (d, i)->
    d.index = i
    d.date = parseDate(d.date)
    d.delay = +d.delay
    d.distance = +d.distance
```

this compiles to something very similar to the OP's sample:

```
_fn = function(d, i) {
  d.index = i;
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.delay = +d.delay;
  return d.distance = +d.distance;
};
for (i = _i = 0, _len = flights.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
  d = flights[i];
  _fn(d, i);
}
```

Use this if you need < ie9 support (forEach supported in IE starting version 9)